# Can We update magento when website is almost ready?

Tags: php, magento

I'm using magento 1.7.0 and my website is almost ready. Due to some unusual response from this version, I want to update this magento version to latest one. But I don't want to change anything else like my theme,its core file have modified n all. Should it be possible to update magento ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory is possible.
An upgrade should run smoothly if you don't have custom extensions installed.

If you do, then make sure that they are compatible with 1.8.1 (latest at the time of writing this).

Now the problems.  There is a biiiiig chance that your theme is not compatible with the 1.8 theme.
A lot has changed in 1.8. The biggest thing is the `form_key` that is now needed when you login, register, add something to the cart or each step of the checkout process (maybe there are other places I just don't know them all).  What this means is that in almost every post request you must send to the controller a value that differs from session to session, for security reasons. You must make all your forms include this form key.

An other big change is the progress on the checkout. Instead of loading every step, in 1.8 only the last step is loaded in the progress sidebar.
Again you may need to change this in your theme.

As a conclusion, If your website is almost ready and you need to release it fast, don't upgrade.
If you want to upgrade it means that you website is not 'almost ready' and you have to spend some time fixing it and making everything compatible with 1.8.

Comment: thank you for suggesting me..I dont thik I should upgrade this..cause site is almost ready and i dont want take any risk at the last moement. only problem with this site is its taking too much time to load.. actually not loading time this is, this is taking time to find the domain means waiting for "xyz.com" is appearing for a long time then it get loaded.